# Remove the name end and add letters instead

Tags: c#

Coding with C#
Want to delete two letters from the back of the name and add some other letters.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name;
        Console.WriteLine("Whats your name ?");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        if (name.EndsWith("ia") == true) 
        {
            string v1 = name.Remove(name.Length - 2);
            v1.Insert(name.Length, "le");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}", v1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

For example if name is Sofia, the Console would write Hello, Sofle
But the program does not start for me.

Comment: `v1 = v1.Insert(name.Length, "le");` but you can after the remove simply write: `v1 = v1 + "le";` or `v1 += "le";`. Also no need of the true: `if ( name.EndsWith("ia") )`. I hope this can help you to enjoy C# coding: [How do I improve my knowledge in C#](http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/CsharpBegin.htm)

Comment: You can also write: `v1 = v1.TrimEnd("ia")` and you avoid using an index that can causes bugs, as using concatenation instead of insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will do what you want if you replace

```
v1.Insert(name.Length, "le");
```

by

```
v1 = v1.Insert(v1.Length, "le");
```

#### Reasons

1. The `Insert` method returns a new string instead of modifying the original.
2. You need to use `v1.Length` instead of `name.Length` because you're adding at the end of `v1`, not `name`.

Answer (score 1):

[Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netcore-3.1) returns a new string so you have to write:

```
v1 = v1.Insert(v1.Length, "le");
```